# Testing / Profiling a hashcode function for java hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

How do I test / profile a hashCode() implementation in Java? i.e. is it distributing my test data reasonably evenly etc? Is there any simple crude way in java API itself?

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hashCodes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (YourHashcodedClass testData: largeCollectionOfTestData) {
    Integer hashCode = Integer.valueOf(testData.hashCode());
    Integer occurrences = hashCodes.get(hashCode);
    if (occurrences == null) {
        occurrences = 0;
    }
    hashCodes.put(hashCode, occurrences+1);
}
```

Then analyze your map for collisions.

Comment: the map contains your hashcodes.  any entry w/ occurrences > 1 is a collision.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you shouldn't have to profile or test the distribution of your `hashCode()` method if you follow best practices. See the hash code recipe below from [*Effective Java*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/). Furthermore even if you don't write it too well, the `HashMap` implementation rehashes your result to reduce collisions:

```
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

You can also use [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to build the hash code for you.

#### [Effective Java 2nd Edition hash code recipe](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=Effective%20Java%20hashcode%20recipe&source=bl&ots=yYCiNip6R_&sig=nwiez5v1ppENzbPWu1jijErKgHI&hl=en&ei=qXyyTbKaMIv4swPi3vj2Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)

- Store some constant nonzero value, say 17, in an `int` variable called `result`.
- Compute an `int` hashcode `c` for each field:

  - If the field is a `boolean`, compute `(f ? 1 : 0)`
  - If the field is a `byte, char, short, int`, compute `(int) f`
  - If the field is a `long`, compute `(int) (f ^ (f >>> 32))`
  - If the field is a `float`, compute `Float.floatToIntBits(f)`
  - If the field is a `double`, compute `Double.doubleToLongBits(f)`, then hash the resulting `long` as in above.
  - If the field is an object reference and this class's `equals` method compares the field by recursively invoking `equals`, recursively invoke `hashCode` on the field. If the value of the field is `null`, return 0.
  - If the field is an array, treat it as if each element is a separate field. If every element in an array field is significant, you can use one of the `Arrays.hashCode` methods added in release 1.5.
- Combine the hashcode `c` into `result` as follows: `result = 31 * result + c;`